# Maintaining sequential uniqueness in database record insertions

Tags: postgresql

In the table provided, how can I ensure that consecutive inserts (for the same id) do not contain duplicate id/value pairs? The goal is to track **changes** in id over time. Rows marked with a strikethrough should not be included.

| id | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-03-26 16:32:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2024-03-26 16:32:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 2024-03-26 16:33:00 | 6 |
| 3 | 2024-03-26 16:33:00 | 3 |
| <strike>2</strike> | <strike>2024-03-26 16:35:11</strike> | <strike>6</strike> |
| 2 | 2024-03-26 16:36:00 | 8 |
| 3 | 2024-03-26 16:40:00 | 7 |
| 3 | 2024-03-26 16:41:00 | 3 |
| <strike>1</strike> | <strike>2024-03-26 16:50:00</strike> | <strike>5</strike> |

My current solution involving triggers seems convoluted, and I'm confident there's a better approach to achieve this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prevent_duplicate_rows()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    latest_partition_time timestamp;
    latest_partition_value my_table.value%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(time) INTO latest_partition_time
    FROM my_table
    WHERE NEW.id = id;
    IF latest_partition_time IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        SELECT value INTO latest_partition_value
        FROM my_table
        WHERE time = latest_partition_time
        AND NEW.id = id;

        IF NEW.value <> latest_partition_value THEN
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_duplicate_rows
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION prevent_duplicate_rows();
```

I also attempted to use a check constraint with a user-defined function, as suggested in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63724835/13227420), but struggled to find a straightforward way to handle violations:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_new_value(_id int, _value int)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$

  SELECT_value != last_value(value) 
                            OVER(PARTITION BY id
                                      ORDER BY time) 
    FROM my_table
      WHERE id = _id;
                        
                        
$$ language sql;



ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT new_value_ck
CHECK(check_new_value(id, value));
```

Comment: In PostgreSQL it is generally discouraged to create check constraints that reference table data other than the new or updated row being checked. See the notes [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for a trigger function using a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prevent_duplicate_rows()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
begin
if new.value = (
   select value from my_table where id = new.id order by "time" desc limit 1
  ) then
  return null;
end if;
return new;
end;
$$;
```

DB Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pATSSCene2UeVQGN6JSnb8/1)

**Please note** that this rule of uniqueness is only maintained in the case of insert-only workflow that disallows updates and deletes of existing records.